# java separating sorted elements in list by their first char

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I would like to separate sorted elements in list by their first char.

```
    public static void printList(List<Miejsce> list) {
        for (Miejsce miejsce : list) {
            System.out.print(miejsce.getNumerMiejsca()+" ");
        }
    }
```

output:

```
A01 A02 A03 A04 A05 A06 A07 A08 B01 B02 B03 B04 B05 B06 B07 B08 C01 C02 C03 C04 C05 C06 C07 C08 D01 D02 D03 D04...
```

what I want to do

```
A01 A02 A03 A04 A05 A06 A07 A08 
B01 B02 B03 B04 B05 B06 B07 B08 
C01 C02 C03 C04 C05 C06 C07 C08 
D01 D02 D03 D04...
```

Comment: Does `miejsce.getNumerMiejsca()` return a `String`?

Comment: @RyanZhang yes, it does

Comment: Cool, I'll help you out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to add a line break every time the first character changes.

There are a few ways we can do this, though the easiest involves preserving the range-based for loop and creating a new variable to store the last letter, so when the current first letter differs from the previous letter, we print a line break.

Additionally, create a `boolean` to flag whether it is the first string to be printed.

Below is an implementation of this.

```
public static void printList(List<Miejsce> list) {
    char lastLetter = '\0'; 
    boolean firstString = true;
    for (Miejsce miejsce : list) {
        if (!firstString && miejsce.getNumerMiejsca().charAt(0) != lastLetter) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(miejsce.getNumerMiejsca()+" ");
        lastLetter = miejsce.getNumerMiejsca().charAt(0);
        firstString = false;
    }
}
```

However, this does create trailing spaces `' '` at the end of each line. If this is a concern, we can ditch the range-based for loop and instead do something like this.

```
public static void printList(List<Miejsce> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i).getNumerMiejsca());
        if(i != list.size()-1 && list.get(i).getNumerMiejsca().charAt(0) != list.get(i+1).getNumerMiejsca().charAt(0)) {
            System.out.print('\n');
        } else {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these implementations should be pretty intuitive and simple.

Comment: Thank you so much, I like the way how you explained this

Comment: However, isn't the `boolean firstString = true` always true?

Comment: You could consider using the object type `Character` for `lastletter` and intializing it with `null`. Then you could just do a check if it is `null` to identify the first iteration instead of introducing an extra boolean variable for that.

Comment: @huga721 You're right. I forgot to set it to false. I have fixed it as an edit. Apologies — I never tested my code.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way with streams:

```
public static void printList(List<Miejsce> list) {
    list.stream()
        .map(Miejsce::getNumerMiejsca)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                num -> num.charAt(0),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toList(),
                        li -> String.join(" ", li))))
        .values()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```